# How to Acess the Path of a file in Resources subfolder (Xamarin.Android)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I have EnglishSD.nbin file in Resources sub Models_folder I am accessing the path like this in my xamarin.android project but I am getting file not found Please help me with your suggestions thanks

[image]

```
var modelPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "D:\\Foldername\\Project Name 
                                                               \\Resources\\Models\\EnglishSD.nbin";

            var sentenceDetector = new EnglishMaximumEntropySentenceDetector(modelPath);
            var sentences = sentenceDetector.SentenceDetect(paragraph);
            return sentences;
```

> Error

```
Error: File not found Error
```

Comment: When you put the `Models` folder in `Resources` , the xamarin android code should not been compiled successfully.

Comment: @Jessie Zhang Thanks for your reply Actually I created Core project (.NetFramework ) in visual studio and I added to the Main Xamarin.android project but I have Training files like EnglishSd.nbin  I have no idea where to add those so I added to xamarin.android project in Resouces Could you tell me where to add this in my core Project

Comment: Yes, we usually put file in Android `Assets` folder. For more details, you can check:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/android-assets?tabs=windows

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with a ".nbin" file, but I would recommend putting it in the Android `Assets` folder instead.

[image]

You can read files from `Assets` like this:

```
public async Task<byte[]> ReadPdfFileAsync()
{
    using (var fileStream = Assets.Open("pdf-file.pdf")
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await fileStream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```